# Tractatus-style paragraph numbering

Tags: numbering, plain-tex

How can I keep track of a decimal number that indicates the current
paragraph's place in a logical hierarchy and print it in the margin of
each paragraph?  (To yield a numbering in the style of Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus).

```
\def\on{}
\def\down{}
\def\up{}

\on
This is the first paragraph, paragraph number 1.

\on
This is paragraph number 2.

\down
This is paragraph number 2.1

\down 2
This is 2.101

\up
This is 2.11

\down
2.111

\up 3
3

\bye
```

<strike>If `\down` is starred, begin with zero.</strike>  If `\up` is
followed by an integer, it should take it as an argument, unless there
is a newline between `\up` and the integer.  An indefinite number of
decimals should be possible.

PS.  I apologize for changing the question after (2) answers have been
given, but I realize I failed to appreciate a feature of Wittgenstein's
numbering: the last decimal is never 0.  Therefore, `\down <n>` is
better than `\down*`, as now demonstrated above.  I think the 0 is
supposed to indicate an additional level of unimportance.

[image]

Comment: `\down*` should be 2.1.0 ? or as you have it 2.10 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just one decimal point.

Comment: so if it is depth 4 and the values are 5,10,11,12, then it's 5.101112 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, all values must be one-digit

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks!  (a way to allow higher values would be using letters as in hexadecimals, but Tractatus doesn't need them : https://tractatus-online.appspot.com/Tractatus/jonathan/D.html

Answer (score 7):

I have more `.` than you clarified in comments and (currently) you need `\up\up` not `\up2` but

[image]

```
% this would be so much easier in latex:-)

\newcount\zzdepth
\newcount\zza
\edef\zzbase{\the\allocationnumber}
\zzdepth\allocationnumber
\newcount\zzb
\newcount\zzc
\newcount\zzd

\def\thezz{{%
\ifnum\zzdepth>\zzbase\relax
\advance\zzdepth-1 %
\expandafter\thezz
\fi
}\the\count\zzdepth.%
}

\everypar{{\bf\thezz} }



\def\on{\advance\count\zzdepth 1\relax}
\def\eatstar*{}
\def\down{\futurelet\tmp\xxdown}
\def\xxdown{%
\ifx*\tmp
\advance\zzdepth 1 \count\zzdepth 0\relax
\expandafter\eatstar
\else
\advance\zzdepth 1 \count\zzdepth 1\relax
\fi}

\def\up{\advance\zzdepth -1 \advance\count\zzdepth 1\relax}

\on
This is the first paragraph, paragraph number 1.

\on
This is paragraph number 2.

\down
This is paragraph number 2.1

\down*
This is 2.10

\up
This is 2.2

\down
This is 2.2.1

\up\up
This is 3

\bye
```

Comment: What would be different if you could use plain LaTeX (no packages)? I found my writing style morph into exactly the situation your macros solve, but I'm wondering if LaTeX can package it up nicer.

Comment: @AlexNelson wouldn't be that different except the section counters and secnumdepth are already allocated so you could re-use them

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Pure plain TeX code that emulates Wittgenstein's output.

```
\newcount\decide
\newcount\current
\newcount\temp
\newcount\level
\newcount\leveli
\newcount\levelii
\newcount\leveliii
\newcount\leveliv
\newcount\levelv
% add more if necessary

\parindent=0pt

\current=0

\def\on{%
  \par
  \global\advance\csname level\romannumeral\current\endcsname by 1
  \makezero
  \startpar
}
\def\up{\par\afterassignment\doup\decide=0}
\def\down{\par\afterassignment\dodown\decide=0}
\def\doup{%
  \ifnum\decide=0 % no number follows
    \global\advance\current by -1
  \else
    \global\advance\current by -\decide
  \fi
  \global\advance\csname level\romannumeral\current\endcsname by 1
  \makezero
  \startpar
}
\def\dodown{%
  \ifnum\decide=0 % no number follows
    \global\advance\current by 1
  \else
    \global\advance\current by \decide
  \fi
  \global\advance\csname level\romannumeral\current\endcsname by 1
  \makezero
  \startpar
}
\def\makezero{%
  \temp=\current
  \loop\ifnum\temp<5
    \advance\temp by 1
    \global\csname level\romannumeral\temp\endcsname=0  
  \repeat
}
\def\startpar{%
  \hangindent=4em
  \printcounters
}
\def\printcounters{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 5em{%
    \temp=0 \decide=0
    \loop\ifnum\temp<5
      \advance\temp by 1
      \ifnum\csname level\romannumeral\temp\endcsname>0
        \decide=\temp
      \fi
    \repeat
    \the\level
    \ifnum\decide>0 .\fi
    \temp=0
    \loop\ifnum\temp<\decide
      \advance\temp by 1
      \the\csname level\romannumeral\temp\endcsname
    \repeat
    \hfil
  }\ignorespaces
}

\on
This is the first paragraph, paragraph number 1.

\on
This is paragraph number 2.

\down 2
This is paragraph 2.01

\on (2.02) \on (2.03) \on (2.04) \on (2.05) \on (2.06) \down (2.061)

\vfill\eject

\on This is 2.062 which goes on for some length in order to 
    make a line break; just add words until necessary

\on
This is paragraph number 2.063

\up 2
This is 2.1

\down
This is 2.11

\on
This is 2.12

\on
This is 2.13

\down
This is 2.131

\up
This is 2.14

\down
This is 2.141

\up
This is 2.15

\down
This is 2.151

\down
This is 2.1511

\on
This is 2.1512

\down
This is 2.15121

\up
This is 2.1513

\on
This is 2.1514

\on
This is 2.1515

\up 4
This is 3

\bye
```

The first page is just to start in the second page like in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A LaTeX3 solution. I made some minor changes to your syntax.

- I added switches for turning paragraph numbering on and off. When it is on, new paragraphs automatically get a new number. (If this is undesirable, it can easily be changed with a couple of lines in the preamble.)
- I provide the number of levels to go up or down as an optional argument to `\up` or `\down` (inside brackets) instead of checking if there is a number there. This is more in line with LaTeX syntax and should be safer as long as no paragraph starts with an opening bracket.
- Digits are converted to base 36 for printing, which means that numbers from `10` to `35` are printed as letters `a` through `z`.
- A warning if issued if a digit exceeds 35 or if you go further `\up` than you should.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% This sequence contains the current paragraph number
\seq_new:N \g_tract_parnumber_seq

% Printing the paragraph number
\cs_new:Nn \tract_parnumber_print:
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \tract_parnumber_print_aux:n
      { \seq_map_function:NN \g_tract_parnumber_seq \tract_parnumber_print_auxi:n }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \tract_parnumber_print_aux:n
  {
    \tl_head:n { #1 }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \tl_count:n { #1 } } > 1
      { . \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \tract_parnumber_print_auxi:n
  { { \tract_number_print:n { #1 } } }
% This function formats a single element of the paragraph number (one digit).
\cs_new:Nn \tract_number_print:n
  { \int_to_base:nn { #1 } { 36 } }

% Functions for manipulating the paragraph number
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumber_reset:
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_tract_parnumber_seq
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tract_parnumber_seq { 0 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumber_advance:
  {
    \group_begin:
      \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_tract_parnumber_seq \l_tmpa_int
      \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_tract_parnumber_seq
        { \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int + 1 } }
      \int_compare:nNnT { \l_tmpa_int } > { 34 }
        {
          \msg_warning:nnx { tractatus } { number-too-high }
            { \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int + 1 } }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
% The up and down functions assume that the paragraph number is advanced afterwards.
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumber_down:n
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_tract_parnumber_seq { 0 } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumber_up:n
  {
    \group_begin:
      \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
        { \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_tract_parnumber_seq \l_tmpa_int }
      \seq_if_empty:NT \g_tract_parnumber_seq
        {
          \msg_warning:nn { tractatus } { top-level-removed }
          \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tract_parnumber_seq { -1296 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }

% Turning numbering on and off
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumbers_on:
  {
    \group_begin:
      \reversemarginpar
      \setlength\marginparwidth{8ex}
      \everypar{
        \tract_parnumber_advance:
        \marginpar{\tract_parnumber_print:}
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tract_parnumbers_off:
  { \group_end: }

% Messages
\msg_new:nnn { tractatus } { number-too-high }
  {
    The~current~paragraph~(sub-)number~exceeds~35,~which~is~the~highest~number~
    that~can~be~printed~as~a~single~digit.~This~number~is~#1.
  }
\msg_new:nnn { tractatus } { top-level-removed }
  {
    You~just~removed~the~top~paragraph~numbering~level.~
    I~will~set~the~counter~to~-zz~=~-1295~as~a~marker.
  }

% Document level commands.
\NewDocumentCommand\resetparnumber { } {
  \tract_parnumber_reset:
}
\NewDocumentCommand\parnumberson { } {
  \tract_parnumbers_on:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \parnumberson \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \parnumbersoff \tract_parnumbers_off:
}
\NewDocumentCommand\parnumbersoff { } { }
\NewDocumentCommand\down { O{1} } {
  \tract_parnumber_down:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\up { O{1} } {
  \tract_parnumber_up:n { #1 }
}

\AtBeginDocument{\resetparnumber}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\parnumberson

This is the first paragraph, paragraph number 1.

This is paragraph number 2.

\down
This is paragraph number 2.1

\down[2]
This is 2.101

\up
This is 2.11

\down
2.111

\up[3]
3

\parnumbersoff

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]