# Wittgenstein's numbering system

Tags: numbering

In his *Tractatus logico-philosophicus*, Wittgenstein uses an unusual numbering system for **paragraphs**, here's how he describes it.

> The decimal figures as numbers of the separate propositions indicate the logical importance of the propositions, the emphasis laid upon them in my exposition. The propositions *n.1*, *n.2*, *n.3*, etc., are comments on proposition No. *n*; the propositions *n.m1*, *n.m2*, etc., are comments on the proposition No. *n.m*; and so on.

## Example

[image: Example]

## Ideas

I see two ways of designing such architecture. The first is the one proposed by the author of the plain Tex question that I cite below (that uses `up` and `down`). The other is to create a `proposition` environment.

```
\begin{proposition}
    Proposition 1
    \begin{proposition}
        Proposition 1.1
    \end{proposition}
    \begin{proposition}
        Proposition 1.2
        \begin{proposition}
             Proposition 1.21
        \end{proposition}
    \end{proposition}
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}[0]
    Proposition 2
    \begin{proposition}
        Proposition 2.0
        \begin{proposition}
             Proposition 2.01
        \end{proposition}
    \end{proposition}
\end{proposition}
```

## Notes

- I don't mind about working with commands or environments, I'm just looking for a practical solution.
- I am aware that [plain Tex solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500062/tractatus-style-paragraph-numbering) exist but I guess the use of LaTeX can simplify macros.

Comment: Could you potentially have proposition X.Y referencing proposition X *outside* the scope of proposition X? For example, *after* proposition Z, say.

Comment: No, the structure is strictly hierarchical. As soon as n.m ceases to appear, it will never again be mentioned in the treaty. This applies at all levels: once the proposition 2. has been stated, none will start with 1.

Comment: "% this would be so much easier in latex:-)" hmmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved your `[0]` option to what seemed to be a more natural place, then

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{propn}
\newcounter{propnn}[propn]
\renewcommand\thepropnn{\thepropn.\arabic{propnn}}
\newcounter{propnnn}[propnn]
\renewcommand\thepropnnn{\thepropnn\textsuperscript{\arabic{propnnn}}}

\newcommand\propdepth{prop}

\newenvironment{proposition}[1][\relax]{%
\edef\propdepth{\propdepth n}%
\par
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\setcounter{\propdepth}{\numexpr#1-1}%
\fi
\refstepcounter{\propdepth}%
\noindent\llap{\csname the\propdepth\endcsname}\indent\ignorespaces
}{%
\par
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
    Proposition 1
    \begin{proposition}
        Proposition 1.1
    \end{proposition}
    \begin{proposition}
        Proposition 1.2
        \begin{proposition}
             Proposition 1.21
        \end{proposition}
    \end{proposition}
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}
    Proposition 2
    \begin{proposition}[0]
        Proposition 2.0
        \begin{proposition}
             Proposition 2.01
        \end{proposition}
    \end{proposition}
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! An explanation of how to add extra depth would be welcome :)

Comment: I assumed from the layout that deeper would not be needed but it just takes a couple of lines  `\newcounter{propnnnn}[propnnn]` for the counter then you need to say how to render it, presumably something like  `\renewcommand\thepropnnnn{\thepropnnn\textsuperscript{.\arabic{propnnnn}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle side note: I think the example in the question uses oldstyle numbers, and is not a superscript.

Comment: It uses superscript for the very last number `\renewcommand\thepropnnnn{\thepropnnn\textsuperscript{\arabic{propnnn}}}`

Comment: @TivV ah OK you are probably right, OK but that's just a matter of changing the \thepropnnn` macros as for any  latex counter so easy enough to have any format.

Comment: However, speaking of formatting, how do you get left-alignment in the margin?

Comment: change `\rlap{...}` to  `\rlap{\makebox[2cm][l]{...}}`

Comment: Assuming you meant `llap` it is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Blincer left-right- one of those:-)

Comment: fwiw, Wittgenstein does **not** use superscripts in the *Tractatus*

Comment: @DG' yep this German/English edition https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.221659/page/n33 doesn't distinguish the second two parts at all I see, I'll leave that to the OP, easy enough to remove the superscripting if desired.